# SR Latch/Racing?

Tags: digital-logic, clock, flipflop, logic-gates, latch

Following truth table resulted from the circuit below. SR(NOR) latch is used.  I have tried several times to trace through the circuit to see how truth table values are produced but its not working. Can someone explain to me what is going on ? This circuit was introduced in conjunction with racing although I am not sure if it has anything to do with it.

**NOTE: "CLOCK" appears as a straight line to show how its connected everything. It is a normal clock that oscillates between 1 and 0. (this is how my instructor drew it).**
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The input to the circuit has a race as the clock and the signal occur together. The input should have been set up on when clock is zero. Note how the input to the following latches are set up properly due to the fact the outputs of this type latch switch on clock going to zero.

Answer (score 1):

As per your truth table it seems that the block you mentioned is SR flipflop not a latch.
A latch is asynchronous, and the outputs can change as soon as the inputs do. And major difference between this flipflop and latch is

```
     latch - level triggered
     flipflop- Edge triggered.
```

so, the given block is the SR flipflop which is negative edge triggered. Then you can understad the given circuit.

whenever the clock goes from high to low the whataver the data is in the input pin is processed to the output. And then it will hold the data. And then next change will be whenever the negative edge clock comes